# How to read an image from drawable to File object in java?

Tags: android, image, file-io, resources, drawable

I have an image in the res folder. I want it to be available in the File(java.io.File) object.

I am using:

```
File f = new File(new URI("drawable/small");
```

where small is the name of the image.

Comment: you can directly use any resource by R.id.icon

Comment: I want to use it in File object. R.id.icon gives int.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
        InputStream ins = getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.icon);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ins));
        StringBuffer sb;
        String line;
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
            sb.append(line);
            }

        File f = new File(sb.toString());
```

You can use openRawResource to copy a binary across from your raw resource folder to the device or in this case the File

Answer (score -1):

Is it something like?

```
File f = new File(Uri.parse("android.resource://com.package.AppName/res/drawable/resource_name"));
```

Comment: ya i want to use something like this. But the above code doesn't work. File does not accept Uri, instead it takes URI.